Need to remove the duplicate node values index based using xslt 1.0
I tried various ways to get rid of the duplicate node values but couldn't achieve the desired result. Below is the input XML.
<before>              
      <class>
         <type>352</type>
         <agent>19133</agent>
         <ins-co>60122</ins-co>        
      </class>
      <class>
         <type>351</type>
         <agent>19355</agent>
         <ins-co>60122</ins-co>        
      </class>     
    </area>
</before>
<after>         
      <class>
         <type>355</type>
         <agent>19355</agent>
         <ins-co>60122</ins-co>                                 
      </class>      
      <class>
         <type>352</type>
         <agent>19133</agent>
         <ins-co>60122</ins-co>                                 
      </class>                                                            
</after>

XSLT used for transformation -
<xsl:template match="/">
    <MaintenanceMessage>            
        <BeforeImage>
            <MaintenanceList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//beforechange/area/stud-class-buckets">
                    <xsl:with-param name="placement">before</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </MaintenanceList>              
        </BeforeImage>
        <AfterImage>
            <MaintenanceList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//beforechange/area/stud-class-buckets">
                    <xsl:with-param name="placement">after</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </MaintenanceList>              
        </AfterImage>
    </MaintenanceMessage>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//before/class">        
        <xsl:param name="placement"/>
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>        
        <xsl:if test="//before/class[$index] != //after/class[$index]">         
            <Maintenance>               
                <xsl:attribute name="index"><xsl:value-of select="$index"/></xsl:attribute>             
                <xsl:variable name="TypeCode">
                    <xsl:call-template name="FieldValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="dyn:evaluate(concat('//MESSAGE/', $placement , '/class[$index]/type'))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$TypeCode = 'null'">
                        <egm:TypeCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <egm:TypeCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$TypeCode"/>
                        </egm:TypeCode>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>               
                <xsl:variable name="AgentCode">
                    <xsl:call-template name="FieldValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="dyn:evaluate(concat('//MESSAGE/', $placement , '/class[$index]/agent'))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$AgentCode = 'null'">
                        <egm:AgentCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <egm:AgentCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$AgentCode"/>
                        </egm:AgentCode>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>               
                <xsl:variable name="InsCoCode">
                    <xsl:call-template name="FieldValue">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="dyn:evaluate(concat('//MESSAGE/', $placement , '/class[$index]/ins-co'))"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$InsCoCode = 'null'">
                        <egm:InsCoCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <egm:InsCoCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$InsCoCode"/>
                        </egm:InsCoCode>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </Maintenance>      
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>
    

Output got -
<MaintenanceMessage>
    <BeforeImage>
        <MaintenanceList>
            <Maintenance index="3">
                <TypeCode>352</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19133</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>                
            </Maintenance>
            <Maintenance index="4">
                <TypeCode>351</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19355</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>                
            </Maintenance>
...            
        </MaintenanceList>
    </BeforeImage>
    <AfterImage>
        <MaintenanceList>
            <Maintenance index="3">
                <TypeCode>355</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19355</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>                
            </Maintenance>
            <Maintenance index="4">
                <TypeCode>352</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19133</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>                
            </Maintenance>
...            
        </MaintenanceList>
    </AfterImage>
</MaintenanceMessage>


Expected result is : The matched TypeCode block should be removed.
<MaintenanceMessage>
    <BeforeImage>
        <MaintenanceList>
            <Maintenance index="3">
                <TypeCode>351</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19355</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>               
            </Maintenance>            
...            
        </MaintenanceList>
    </BeforeImage>
    <AfterImage>
        <MaintenanceList>
            <HazardMaintenance index="3">
                <TypeCode>355</TypeCode>
                <AgentCode>19355</AgentCode>
                <InsCoCode>60122</InsCoCode>   
...            
        </MaintenanceList>
    </AfterImage>
</MaintenanceMessage>


The expectation is, The matched TypeCode block should be removed.
Am not so competent in XSLT. Appreciate the help. Thank you

Your question is not clear. Consider reducing the example code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve]. Also remove the xslt-2.0 tag if you are looking for an XSLT 1.0 solution. You also tagged this as muenchian-grouping - but I see no attempt to use the Muenchian grouping method in your XSLT.

Here is an example of using Muenchian grouping to get distinct values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78419943/3016153

Thank you @michael.hor257k for the advice. If you see the TypeCode - 355 is the duplicate value exists in beforeimage & afterimage. Am trying to get rid of the TypeCode - 355 from both beforeimage & afterimage irrespective of the index. Thanks a lot for the reply.

@michael.hor257k any help would be appreciated.

I still see no effort on your part to implement Muenchian grouping.  Do not expect me to write your code for you.

@michael.hor257k Apologies, need some insight or advice on what point I made the mistake. Let me try on Muenchian grouping.  Thank you

You made the mistake of not trying. And you are making it worse by wasting my time.
